# Why does using cout on *max_element(v.begin(),v.end(),c); throw this huge error?

Tags: c++, stl

```
STL.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
STL.cpp:56:86: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >((* &std::cout),((const char*)"The Point with the largest Y value is ")) << std::max_element<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, std::vector<Point> >, Compare_Y>(v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<Point, std::allocator<Point> >(), v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end<Point, std::allocator<Point> >(), (c, Compare_Y())).__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<Point*, std::vector<Point> >()’
STL.cpp:56:86: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40:0,
             from STL.cpp:2:
```

...etc....

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:546:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:546:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
STL.cpp:56:86: note:   cannot convert ‘std::max_element<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, std::vector<Point> >, Compare_Y>(v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<Point, std::allocator<Point> >(), v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end<Point, std::allocator<Point> >(), (c, Compare_Y())).__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<Point*, std::vector<Point> >()’ (type ‘Point’) to type ‘const unsigned char*’
```

Most people who have a similar error seem to have a mistyped a std::'something' of some sort, but that isn't the case here as far as I know. I'm mentally burnt and a little befuddled at the moment. I only copied 1/4th of the verbose text block that I was given as a result of this error. My code is below. I know it's my first time using STL algorithms, but everything seems to be in order. I guess this is how we learn.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Point{
        int x,y;//Integer coordinates for simplicity
public:
        Point();
        Point(int, int);

        double get_Y() const {return y;}

        void Print();
};

Point::Point(){//Initialize blank Points to blank values (zero)
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
}

Point::Point(int a, int b){
        x = a;
        y = b;
}

void Point::Print(){
        cout<< "Point: (" << x << "," << y << ")" << '\t';

}
//comparison function for comparing Point class objects
struct Compare_Y{
        bool operator()(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
                { return p1.get_Y() > p2.get_Y(); }
};

int main(){

        //Store 10 Points in any container, initialize, and print each Point
        vector<Point> v;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        v.push_back(Point(i*5,i*10));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        v[i].Print();
        }

        //Write function to find Point with maximum y coordinate by any STL Algorithm (See C++ site w/ them)
        //Return the point with the max y coord. Return the x AND y here.

        Compare_Y c;
        cout << "The Point with the largest Y value is " << *max_element(v.begin(),v.end(),c);

return 0;

}
```

No this isn't homework. It's practice that isn't for a grade, and we were told that we had to use at least one STL algorithm, which is why I opted for *max_element since our TA used it in an example that I took notes on.

Comment: You're trying to print a `Point` with `operator<<`. You haven't specified how to print a `Point`, so it doesn't guess at it.

Comment: Ohhh shoot. I need to override the << operator for my Point class

Comment: Yes.  But it's a lovely error message, isn't it?

Comment: FWIW, I think Clang gives a pretty reasonable error for figuring out the problem: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a097b555a14285c

Comment: Also, one last bit. Overriding << fixed the compiler errors, can confirm, but there was a logic error. I kept getting that the Max Y value was found in the coord (0,0). I just needed to switch the `>` in Compare_Y s return statement to be `<`